# null value is getting while calling a parent class method

Tags: java

I have following classes.

```
public class TestController {
    protected ElementManager mElementManager;   
    public ElementManager getElementManager() {
        return this.mElementManager;
    }
}

public class ElementManager {
public final void clearTextField(String description, By by) {
        System.out.println("clearTextField: " + description);
        getElement(by).clear();
    }
}
```

The below class extends the `TestController` and calling the `clearTextField()` method in `ElementManager .`

but am getting error that `eManager` is getting as `null` value.

```
public class PTestController extends TestController {
ElementManager eManager = this.getElementManager();
 eManager.clearTextFieldById("Pa","kkkk");

}
```

what is wrong with my code

Comment: protected ElementManager mElementManager; 
You never instantiated your mElementManager, meaning it still has the default value, being null.

Comment: you have not initialized `mElementManager` in your `TestController` class,  you can initialize it either using constructor or a setter for `mElementManager`

Comment: getElementManager  returns null since you have not yet initialized  mElementManager  in your  TestController  class.

Comment: I guess you got downvoted because this issue would be easy to pick up with debugger. Tip: try to debug code before asking question to avoid situation in which community does trivial debugging for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the entire code, you are not initializing `mElementManager`. Hence, it will be `null`, and any attempt to use it will result in a `NullPointerException`.

To solve this problem, you could just initialize it in the parent class:

```
public class TestController {
    protected ElementManager mElementManager = new ElementManager(); // Here!
    public ElementManager getElementManager() {
        return this.mElementManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

1. You didn't initialized your `mElementManager` in `TestController`. Did you forgot to add a constructor there?

`public TestController() {
    mElementManager = new ElementManager();
}`

2. Your class `PTestController` seems to be badly written. Try to get some basic understanding on how to write a class in Java.